# Get Special Folder

Tags: c#

**Please just answer the question**
otherwise do not respond to this question.

Let me start again. How do I use this class, which extends the internal Environment.GetSpecialFolder?

I don't want specialroots

```
root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder)
```

Because I want to use this for other purposes other than `.NET`.

For example, how do I call `Favorites = 6` location by a button click?

```
public class EnvironmentFolders
{

public enum SpecialFolder
{
    AdministrativeTools = 48,
    //{user name}\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools 
    ApplicationData = 26,
    //{user name}\Application Data 
    CommonAdministrativeTools = 47,
    //All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools 
    CommonApplicationData = 35,
    //All Users\Application Data 
    CommonDesktopDirectory = 25,
    //All Users\Desktop 
    CommonDocuments = 46,
    //All Users\Documents 
    CommonFavorites = 31,
    CommonNonLocalizedStartup = 30,
    //non localized common startup 
    CommonPrograms = 23,
    //All Users\Programs 
    CommonStartMenu = 22,
    //All Users\Start Menu 
    CommonStartup = 24,
    //All Users\Startup 
    CommonTemplates = 45,
    //All Users\Templates 
    ControlPanel = 3,
    //My Computer\Control Panel 
    Cookies = 33,
    DesktopDirectory = 16,
    //{user name}\Desktop 
    Favorites = 6,
    //{user name}\Favorites 
    Fonts = 20,
    //windows\fonts 
    History = 34,
    InternetCache = 32,
    LocalApplicationData = 28,
    //{user name}\Local Settings\Application Data (non roaming) 
    MyDocuments = 5,
    //My Documents 
    MyPictures = 39,
    //C:\Program Files\My Pictures 
    NetworkShortcuts = 19,
    //{user name}\nethood 
    NonLocalizedStartup = 29,
    //non localized startup 
    Printers = 4,
    //My Computer\Printers 
    PrintHood = 27,
    //{user name}\PrintHood 
    ProgramFiles = 38,
    //C:\Program Files 
    ProgramFilesCommon = 43,
    //C:\Program Files\Common 
    Programs = 2,
    //Start Menu\Programs 
    Recent = 8,
    //{user name}\Recent 
    RecycleBin = 10,
    //{desktop}\Recycle Bin 
    SendTo = 9,
    //{user name}\SendTo 
    StartMenu = 11,
    //{user name}\Start Menu 
    Startup = 7,
    //Start Menu\Programs\Startup 
    System = 37,
    //GetSystemDirectory() 
    Templates = 21,
    UserProfile = 40,
    //USERPROFILE 
    Windows = 36
    //GetWindowsDirectory() 
}

[DllImport("shfolder.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, int nFolder, IntPtr hToken, int dwFlags, StringBuilder lpszPath);

/// <summary> 
/// Get an environment folder path for Windows environment folders 
/// </summary> 
/// <returns>A string pointing to the special path</returns> 
/// <remarks></remarks> 
public static string GetPath(SpecialFolder folder)
{
    StringBuilder lpszPath = new StringBuilder(260);
    SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, (int)folder, IntPtr.Zero, 0, lpszPath);
    return lpszPath.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: Using interop to do what .NET can handle perfectly well on its own?  This smells like copypasta from a C/C++ programmer who just moved to .NET and couldn't be bothered to read the docs.  Refactor!

Comment: "for example how do I call (Favorites = 6) location by a button click?" We want to help, but don't understand what you mean by that. It *sounds* like you're asking how to use the `EnvironmentFolders` class to get the location of the current user's 'Favorites' folder when that user clicks a button. (In a Windows Form? On an ASP.NET page? Dunno.) That's confusing, because I think all three answers have explained that. Please try to rephrase the question so we know what you want to do.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Edit: if you've inherited the code you've shown us and need to use it for some reason (instead of the built-in .NET method that appears to do the same thing), you should be able to use it like this:

```
string path = EnvironmentFolders.GetPath(EnvironmentFolders.SpecialFolders.Fonts);
```

Having said that, the `Environment` class has a public method that does nearly the same thing, [`GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx):

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites);
```

The [reflected code in .NET](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) looks exactly like the code in your class, except it adds two things: it verifies that the parameter value is defined in the enumeration (since you can pass any integer to the method) and it demands that the caller has path discovery permission (a new `FileIOPermission`). Is it that last requirement you're trying to work around?

Both methods are **static**, meaning you access them through the type that contains them, not an instance of that type:

```
 // Like this
 EnvironmentFolders.GetPath(...);

 // Not this
 EnvironmentFolders folders = new EnvironmentFolders();
 folders.GetPath(...);
```

See the .NET documentation about [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Well i do need this class. i know how to call (SpecialFolder). my question is how to use deze clas. thank you for the input.

Comment: Nice solution.
But i have a question, how can i get the RecycleBin folder ?

Comment: how to get RecycleBin path by using Environment class ?

Answer (score 11):

```
string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this added to the click event of your button.

```
String path = EnvironmentFolders.GetPath(EnvironmentFolders.SpecialFolder.Favorites)
//do something with the path.
```

You need more info??

ADDED ON EDIT: Comments are right the method is static this way should work (at least, it worked when I try it on a console app).

Comment: You're right that perhaps this is a basic Forms question. (Though `GetPath` is a *static* method on `EnvironmentFolders`.)