# image load Visual Studio 2010 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm having problem loading images to my project. 
I have the image in a folder named microassig this folder is on my desktop, this folder is to be sent online to my tutor, thats my line of code:

```
private Image imageOpen = Image.FromFile("\microassig\openOff.bmp");
```

I don't want to put the directory c:/ because is directory will be different from mine hence why i'm just using the ("\microassig\openOff.bmp");

The problem is that the image doesn't load.

Comment: You need to provide more details - is it a web application? a winforms application? what error are you getting? please note that you're escaping unwanted characters: add a `@` to `Image.FromFile(@"\microassig .....");`

Answer (score 0):

Locate your project's

> bin\debug folder

You can do this by *right-clicking on your project solution and clicking Open in Windows Explorer*.

*Store/Save* the file as

> openOff.bmp

Then you can just do:

```
private Image imageOpen = Image.FromFile("openOff.bmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the `Image.FromFile`. You need to add the image as a resource into the project. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The \ doesn't imply your desktop. You should use `GetFolderPath` for that (See [C# Get Special Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947185/c-sharp-get-special-folder))
There are a few ways to go about this. You could add your image as a resource.

Or, more in the line of what you are already doing you could change your code to something like this:

```
private Image imageOpen = Image.FromFile("openOff.bmp");
```

Then move the `openOff.bmp` to your bin folder (where the exe is saved).

While you keep the `openOff.bmp` in the same folder as your executable it should find it.