# How do I set the output directory in c# using code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, output

I have a windows form program currently outputting to my desktop, It is a windows form that outputs a HTML. I understand I can change the Output directory using visual studio in the way described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms165410(v=vs.100).aspx)

However I want to code in an output path that will override any Visual Studio settings. Something along the lines of...

> outputPath = [path/string]

I've tried searching for this but all I can find is how to do it using visual studio.

I want to avoid using FolderBrowserDialog or SaveFileDialog as they promt the user to select a path, which is not what I want.

Comment: Where do you want that code (and why)? The path is stored in the project file, it would be meaningless anywhere else

Comment: The link you reference is for the output of *building* the application (i.e. where the .exe goes), but it sounds like you are asking about *output from the program* (i.e. where it writes/saves files). These are two very different things.

Comment: Output from the program.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you'd like to change the output directory of one of the things your code generates.

Perhaps this is what you are searching (Enviroment.SpecialFolder): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx

Implementation sample: 
[C# Get Special Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947185/c-sharp-get-special-folder)

Or if you'd like a different path you can set it like this:

```
string path = "C:\\Example\\V1\\file.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

By default a program is writing files into its current working directory (if you do not set a path information while creating the file).

If you want to write to a different directory you can either set the filename with a path included (see answer by usselite).

Otherwise you can use the Directory.SetCurrentDirectory method to change you current working directory of the program.

Hope it helps.