# How to get Documents Folder path on Windows 10 IoT. UWP APP

Tags: c#, .net

I want to read file content which is located in System Documents folder, but I can't find the path of the folder from code. Who can help me do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Get Special Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947185/c-sharp-get-special-folder)

Comment: what did you try so far ?