# How to "Process.Start" using general folder paths?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the "hosts" file location for me

`C:Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

And when i want to open that folder i can open it like this

`Process.Start(@"C:Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts");`

But not everyone is using "C" disk so is there any way to Specify all disks?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947185/get-special-folder

Comment: No, but you can look up the Windows directory through System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR") (or SYSTEMROOT)

Comment: `Environment.SystemDirectory` + `Path.Combine()`.

Comment: Don't mess with my `hosts` file!

Comment: @PoulBak i am just making a hosts file editor chill :D i am not using these for bad things