# Why the current path from an executable file returns null? (C#, Path.GetDirectoryName())

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-8.0

I created a program (C#) that use a data base file for work.

I used a string to represents the path of this file (returned by the Path.GetDirectoryName() function) and worked before I published with Visual Studio.

So I tested the executable file generated by the publish method, unfortunately, doesn't work. I investigated the problem and I discovered that this function (Path.GetDirectoryName()) returned a null value for my string path. Why this function works before the publish method and doesn't after?

The block of code that I tried:

```cs
    public class CargaDao 
    {
        static private string caminhoDoBanco = "";

        public void inicializarBanco()
        {
            string diretorioBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            caminhoDoBanco = Path.Combine(diretorioBase, "Gollog.db");
        }
    }
// there is more methods of course but is not relevant for the moment.
```

but the string, like I said, get a null value.

This problem generated other problems like an error when I use Path.Combine() because my string is passed for this function.

Comment: Are you publishing it as 1 output file? I've read about dynamic loaded assemblies don't have an [Assembly.Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-8.0). I don't know if these are two different things. but might be related?

Comment: If `Path.GetDirectoryName()` is returning null, what are you passing into it? https://dotnetfiddle.net/TKQG8B

Comment: Side note: the database file shouldn't be in the same folder as the executable.  Use the SpecialFolders enumeration to determine a more suitable location.  See [Get Special Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1947185/719186)

Comment: When you publish are you using [Single-file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)? From the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-8.0#remarks) for [Assembly.Location Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-8.0): "In .NET 5 and later versions, for bundled assemblies, the value returned is an empty string."

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You're right! I'm using Single-file deployment and I didn't know about the missing Assembly.Location. To fix that, I don't use Single-file deployment anymore. Now the executable file works well. Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanDodds Yes, That's the source of the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before in the comments, the problem is because the [Single-file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli) make the [Assembly.Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-8.0) returns an empty string in .NET 5 and later versions. You can try another methods to get the current absolute path of your executable file.

Unfortunately, i don't see a solution to dependencies that use the Assembly.Location without changing them. If that's your case, you might consider changing the deployment method.